# android + php also echo null

Tags: php, android

I need to use android + php, but php also echo `null` ???? I don't know is anywhere have some error? I have search some information, I check I have add Thread, and I have include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please give me some suggest!

php:

android:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     setContentView(R.layout.foodrestaurdetail);
     Intent intent = this.getIntent();
       name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
       vendor_sn = intent.getStringExtra("vendor_sn");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),vendor_sn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     getActionBar().setTitle(name); 

    // setupWebView();//載入Webview
           txtMessage = name;

         Thread t = new Thread(new sendPostRunnable(name));
          t.start();
}


 private String sendPostDataToInternet(String strTxt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(MAP_URL);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", strTxt));
    try{
        httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new        DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);
         if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            String strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            return strResult;

         }

    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
         Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(),     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

 class sendPostRunnable implements Runnable{

     String strTxt = null;


     public sendPostRunnable(String strTxt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.strTxt = strTxt;
     }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String result = sendPostDataToInternet(strTxt);

          mHandler.obtainMessage(REFRESH_DATA, result).sendToTarget();
    }

 }
```

Comment: You call Toast in catch blocks. But that is in a thread. That is not possible. Return e.getMessage() as result.

Comment: `but php also echo null` ??? I see no echo null. Moreover you are not reading the echos from php. So how would you know?

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost is deprecated. I recommend use Volley library is simply, easy and usefull.

Here a example:

```
// Tag used to cancel the request
String  tag_string_req = "string_req";



String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/string_response.html";

ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();     

StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            });
```

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

Another example using parameters:

```
// Tag used to cancel the request
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json";

ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();     

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "Androidhive");
            params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
            params.put("password", "password123");

            return params;
        }

    };
```

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/